# Android progressbar in a listview is always indeterminate

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a fixed progress on items in a ListView.  I only see an indeterminate spinning circle in the ListView.... what am I doing wrong? (I'm sure the answer is simple... I'm just not seeing it)

For the following adapter layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/some_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Code:

```
public class SomeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameTextView;
    ProgressBar valueProgressBar;
}

public BestChoiceListAdapter(Context context, List<MyItem> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.some_text);
        holder.valueProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.some_progress);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MyItem optionItem = getItem(position);

    holder.nameTextView.setText(optionItem.getOptionName());
    int progress = (int) (optionItem.getOptionValue());

    holder.valueProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is to apply the horizontal style to it:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/some_progress"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

This will set up all the attributes you will otherwise need to add manually to apply a determinate progress mode.

If you're curious, this is what that system style looks like, in case you wanted to apply the properties individually:

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

HTH

Comment: That did it!  I wish this was a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Change the [indeterminate mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android%3aindeterminate) to false!

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/some_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    />
```